# Live searching of external data based on any character - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, fetch

I have input field, which when you click, the list of fetched data shows up. Now I need to be able to search through the data based on any letter the data includes.

Example:
I have list of different colors - when I type in input field letter L - all colors that has this letter gets filtered across  - bLack, yeLLow, bLue, etc....

```
const colorInformations = "secretURL";

const [colorData, setColorData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        getColorInfo();
    }, []);
    const getColorInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(colorInformations);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const { array1, array2 } = jsonData;
        const combinedData = array1.map(({ data1 }, i) => ({
          ...data1,
          ...array2[i].data2
        }));
        setColorData(combinedData); 
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
   };
```

Fetched Data:

```
 { colorData && colorData.map(( data1, data2,  index)  =>
        <li key={"index" + index}>
                    <div className="col-6 text ">
                      <h5>{data1.name} </h5>
                      <p>{data2.color} </p>  
        </li>
         )}
```

For input I am trying to do this:

```
<input type="text" onChange={handleSearchChange} value={search} />
```

And handleSearchChange function:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
 }
```

Here I got stuck, what I need to finish is:

1. Filter the data based on letters - when L is typed all colors with L in are filtered
2. When I click on specific color it needs to be shown in input form and it has to be remembered in list - so when list is opened again the clicked color is still active

I know I should use .filter() function - I am just not sure how and where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- add a new state for filteredData.

```
const [filteredColorData, setFilteredColorData] = useState([]);
```

2-  onMount set the fetched data to the filtered data along with the actual data source.

```
const getColorInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(colorInformations);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      const { array1, array2 } = jsonData;
      const combinedData = array1.map(({ data1 }, i) => ({
        ...data1,
        ...array2[i].data2
      }));
       setColorData(combinedData);
       setFilteredColorData(combinedData); // set fetched Data.
     } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
     }
 };
```

3- render the filtered data rather than the actual data.

```
 { 
    filteredColorData && filteredColorData.map(( data1, data2,  index)  =>
      <li key={"index" + index}>
        <div className="col-6 text ">
          <h5>{data1.name} </h5>
          <p>{data2.suggestion} </p>  
        </div>
      </li>
    ) 
  }
```

4- implement the filter functionality which filters the data and set the filtered data,
and rerender it to every user input.

```
useEffect(() => {
    filterdata();
  }, [search])

  const filterdata = () => {  
    const filtered = colorData && colorData.filter((data1) => {
      return data1.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase())
    })

    setFilteredColorData(filtered);
  }
```

also check this link for inspiration
[live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-austin-089oc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Jane, you need to use it in the useEffect hook as the code above shows.

Comment: I see, it was my miss-reading. Although, I am having an error : attributes.name.toLowerCase.startWith is not a function. I'll update my post with your solution.

Comment: @Jane, probably you have a mistyping , startsWith not startWith.

Comment: That was unfortunately not the issue. But thanks for noticing!

Comment: the post should be correctly updated now. @samehanwar Issue is still the same, when I am trying to type in input the error comes up.

Comment: @Jane, can you show me how is the output object of the fetched data looks like?

Comment: you mean output on frontend or the json data ? Because fetching output works just fine, I am able to fetch the data, but I am not able to search.

Comment: @Jane,  the json data, I just need to see how the format looks like.

Comment: Post is updated with json data @samehanwar

Comment: @Jane, i found mistyping in the above code.  toLowerCase function should have (); data1.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(search.toLowerCase()). solution updated

Comment: @Jane, also i don't think data2 property is exists in the filteredData object filteredColorData && filteredColorData.map(( data1, data2,  index)  => should be: filteredColorData && filteredColorData.map(( data1,  index)  =>

Comment: That was it, thank you @samehawr for your time and helping me with understanding.